# Conference that accepted my paper does not yet have a Digital Library link

Tags: conference, online-publication

My paper got accepted for a conference in July 2019 and I even presented my work there. The main page of the conference says they will post the Digital Library link for the 2019 proceedings as soon as it becomes available.In [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45537/what-is-the-duration-between-a-conference-and-its-online-proceedings?rq=1) post, the answerer has said that publishing the proceedings online can even take up to 6 months. More than 6 months have passed and nothing from that conference is on IEEE Xplore yet. Is it normal for this to happen?

**EDIT:**

In [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/117701/submitting-conference-paper-to-google-scholar-when-proceedings-not-available?rq=1) post, one answerer has said it is not unusual for conferences to take 6 months to publish their proceedings.

Comment: I'd email or tweet someone from the conference to ask if you haven't already. If you want the link for something particular I'd mention that too - "I was hoping to include a link to the paper in XYZ"

Comment: @Rup I emailed them some months ago and a short while back but I have not received a response from them.